# Struggling with Join with and

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the account number for a product by joining a table.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6GJFqFqrNrDgMd3fnmEwG/3

My account table is structured like:

```
| account_no | line_number | content |
| ---------- | ----------- | ------- |
| CQ01       | 5           | CUST1   |
| CQ01       | 6           | Q       |
| CQ88       | 5           | CUST1   |
| CQ88       | 6           | P       |
| CQ22       | 5           | CUST2   |
| CQ22       | 6           | P       |
```

My product table is structured like

```
| warehouse | product | customer | location |
| --------- | ------- | -------- | -------- |
| 55        | ABC DEF | CUST1    | P        |
```

My query I have built is

```
select p.*, a.account_no from products p
left join accounts a on 
    (a.content = p.customer and a.line_number = 5)
    and
    (a.content = p.location and a.line_number = 6);
```

unfortunately results in a NULL for account_no

```
| warehouse | product | customer | location | account_no |
| --------- | ------- | -------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 55        | ABC DEF | CUST1    | P        |            |
```

which is not the result I am after.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

My expected output would be:

```
| warehouse | product | customer | location | account_no |
| --------- | ------- | -------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 55        | ABC DEF | CUST1    | P        | CQ88       |
```

As my accounts table only has account_no = 'CQ88' when line_number 5 is 'CUST1' and line_number 6 = 'P'

Comment: Please share your expected output.

Comment: You need to join accounts twice, once for each line number.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s6B4jcyhMtvGHCvp8FD5A3/0

Comment: @Ian go for my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I needed to re-structure my accounts table so there were one row per account_no

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6GJFqFqrNrDgMd3fnmEwG/6

I then performed a simple join

```
select p.*, new_accounts.account_no from products p
left join (      
select distinct a.account_no, concat(b.content , '-',c.content) as 'custloc' from accounts a
left join (select * from accounts where line_number = 5) b on a.account_no = b.account_no
left join (select * from accounts where line_number = 6) c on a.account_no = c.account_no
  ) new_accounts ON concat(p.customer,'-',p.location) = new_accounts.custloc;
```

resulted in

```
| warehouse | product | customer | location | account_no |
| --------- | ------- | -------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 55        | ABC DEF | CUST1    | P        | CQ88       |
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want two joins:

```
select p.*,
       a5.account_no as customer_account_no,
       a6.account_no as location_account_no
from products p left join
     accounts a5
     on a5.content = p.customer and
        a5.line_number = 5 left join
     accounts a6
     on a6.content = p.location and
        a6.line_number = 6;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select p.*, a.account_no from products p
inner join accounts a on 
    (a.content = p.customer and a.line_number = 5)
inner join accounts b on 
    (b.content = p.location and b.line_number = 6) and a.account_no  = b.account_no
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly this picks up two rows. It results with an account_no "CQ01" which is not what I need. In my accounts table, CQ01 has a reference to CUST1 and location "Q", but my product is looking for CUST1 and location "P"

Comment: Not possible to return two rows

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself ! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer